# How to get the metadata of a file in SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, metadata, spfile

I am trying to get the name property of a file on SharePoint ?

If I try to get the metadata of the columns I created, I can get this data with this method

**file** is SPFile.

```
if (file.GetProperty("DocId") != null)
{
    docId = file.GetProperty("DocId").ToString();
}
```

But when I try to get the name

```
if (file.GetProperty("Name") != null)
{
    docId = file.GetProperty("Name").ToString();
}
else {...}
```

it goes to else statement.

Where do I go wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's OK after I use

```
file.Item.Name;
```

Answer (score 4):

Most likely you want to look at properties of an SPItem associated with the SPFile in a document library - [SPFile.GetListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.getlistitem).

You can also enumerate all properties of the file with [SPFile.Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.properties) to see that name of "file name" property is something like "vti_title".

Comment: It's OK after I use

file.Item.Name;